# Let floating div stretch to fit text only by height

Tags: html, css

I have floating div's displaying like a table with multiple rows and 3 columns for a php application where the titles are longer than others. I want to control the height so they don't stretch too wide, but I want to allow any title to fit.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omarel/sbjg4c4n/4/

UPDATE: the code below works.

HTML
     
         Short title

```
     <div id="editbtn" class="floatit">update</div>


     <div id="deltebtn" class="floatit"> delete</div>

  <div id="vidtitle" class="floatit" style="width:400px;">Long title that will go out of the div</div> 

     <div id="editbtn" class="floatit">update</div>


     <div id="deltebtn" class="floatit"> delete</div>

     </div>
```

CSS
       .floatit {
                  float:left; display:inline-block;
                  padding:5px 10px 10px 10px;
              }

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here. Can you mock up some before and after images or something like that?

Comment: wow. it seems like my code already worked duh! While I was updating the fiddle to make it more obvious I noticed there was no problem. The long text fit: http://jsfiddle.net/omarel/sbjg4c4n/4/

Comment: Well you gave the video titles a width of 400 so normally text would respect that width unless you force the text to not wrap.